# If you dredge and move ocean floor deposit onto Russia and create mountains, can we influence sea level and temperature?

Tags: geoengineering

A thought was you could create large, reflective white snow area, and offset the ocean rise.  Curious to know if this has potential effect on climate crisis.  As a bystander I know that if you bury an army they aren't going to be fighting anymore but I am most curious about the effect on Earth if such a project could be taken on.  Did read once about super volcanos in Russian land, and could this in-fact protect against those going off too?

I've seen all kinds of dredging-ops and its effectively a vacuum ship of sort.  That's the kind of operation I'm thinking of?

Edit:
What focuses this effort any more?  I am choosing the area of the earth, choosing the operation type, and taken from where...  Time frame I suppose is whatever.. Obviously a huge operation and it could take hundreds of years but so does climate change... I dunno I feel like you people are bullying me, As Usual.  Every, single time.

Comment: if you feel like anybodyis bullying you you flag it for moderator attention,we have this thing called our code of conduct anybody breaking the rules will first get a warning if this does not help the user might be removed from the site..you can read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Probably, the question got closed because it's a "what would happen if" type question

Comment: i worked in mining for 7y, and did AI fatigue analysis using tensor algorithms on subjects in thousands of vehicles.  I personally could shell from vehicle to vehicle and check the inferences 15 frames per second in real time across a fleet of Thousands of mining vehicles.  Thats what you need here.  This isnt a 'What If' question.  Your response is malpractice because notice: NOBODY in the WORLD is suggesting ideas.  This is an operation thats actually Feasible according to ChatGPT.  Every, Single Forum is a Bully. 100 everests = 2ft.  ~15-50 years rough figures.  feasible and will be bullied

Comment: i am ALWAYS bullied by EVERY moderator in EVERY forum.   Thats why ChatGPT destroys this crap.  you bring nothing, NOTHING but misery to every single post I bring.  Every single thing is intuitive and bright and its shut down immediately by trolling scammers.  Notice: YOU are going down now, MODERATORS.  The only thing they do is creep people out.  Ask any random person and they will say ew forums people are nasty in there.  Correct!

Comment: The moment I speak my mind, like a swarm of bees these creeps just come in hey you are multi-personality or you are a menace you dont follow the rules. The only thing these policies do is shuttle hurt people over to reddit so that they can drop their suicide note in a fake little society we have built called 'web2' ... Destroy it, now.  I refuse to participate in this, never have!  But I do notice Patterns, and the macro patterns of 'Internet Community' is anti-human.  Just a Cache of discussion to process for a proper response to inquiry.  GOOD.  Take it into context, for the better of humans

Comment: To protect themselves so they can 'freely speak', people like user253751 come in with newly/regularly made randomized accounts.  Thats the way I see people talk on here.  The possibility of anonymous user happening to find this deleted post is LOL.  It just shows you every person operates under terror on here.

Comment: This should be 'brought back' in light of meaningful info.  But, this site is run entirely by an army of dominators.  Its basically all you do is dominate and move on, meh delete account meeeeeh you are trolls and why should I submit a troll report to troll HQ?  like google, i would rather remove you from favorites and stick with one site.